# How do I use SQL to select only top level folders from a table of folders

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of folders and I want to return only the top level folders.

For example, if the original table (tblFolders) has a single column (Fldrs) as below:

**Fldrs**

```
C:\Folder1
C:\Folder1\Subfolder1
C:\Folder1\Subfolder2
C:\Folder2\Subfolder1
```

I'd like to return:

```
C:\Folder1
C:\Folder2\Subfolder1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's your RDBMS? Different engines have different string processing capabilities

Comment: If you add `C:\Folder2\Subfolder2` to the sample data, will your wanted result change?

Comment: Good question jarlh.  In that case I would want the answer to include both C:\Folder2\Subfolder1 and C:\Folder2\Subfolder2.  Only folders currently in the table can be considered for top level folders.

Comment: My RDBMS is Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Okay, I've tagged your request with `sql-server` accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to select all folders for which *not exists* a parent folder. The most readable query should hence have a `NOT EXISTS` clause.

```
select *
from tblfolders f
where not exists
(
  select null
  from tblfolders p
  where f.fldr like p.fldr + '_%'
);
```

In a `LIKE` pattern, the `_` represents one character, the `%` represents zero or more characters. `_%` is hence one or more characters. Thus we make sure the child folder path is longer than the parent folder path.

Comment: Thanks so much Thorsten.  Your feedback was very helpful and informative.  Upon a comparison of results your answer is indeed yielding expected results and my posted answer has the shortcoming you noted (only returns top folders that have child folders), as well as returning undesired 2nd level folders if 3rd level folders exist.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out and I'm posting the answer that I found.  Feel free to comment on potential improvements.

```
select distinct F2.fldr as TopLevelFolders 
from tblFolders F1
join tblFolders F2 on F1.fldr like F2.fldr + '%'
where F1.fldr <> F2.fldr
order by F2.fldr
```

Comment: It is good you put some effort into this and have come up with a solution yourself. Your query only returns top folders that have child folders, though. You can easily test things on dbfiddle.uk: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2e577576012d35465ab88f2656fbd2e1

Comment: Except for bridge tables that we need to implement m:n relations, my rule of thumb is: only join tables the data of which I want to have in my results. Restrictions on the other hand belong in the `WHERE` clause. For lookups I use `[NOT] IN` for simple things and `[NOT] EXISTS` for more complicated conditions. (Sometimes a lookup can even be made with `<`, `>`, `<>`, and `=`. E.g. `where order_date = (select max(order_date) from ...)`. Don't join, when you don't have to. `DISTINCT` is a typical indicator that you've joined too many data.